# Find monday of current week in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time, timestamp

I am trying to get the timestamp of monday at 00:00 of the current week in python. I know that for a specific date, the timestamp can be found using

```
baseTime = int(datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime(2020,1,1)))
```

However, I want my program to automatically find out, based on the date, which date monday of the current week was, and then get the timestamp. That is to say, it would return different dates this week and next week, meaning different timestamps.

I know that the current date can be found using

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use below program after importing datetime and timedelta from datetime

            today = datetime.now().date()
            monday = today - timedelta(days = today.weekday())

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> I am trying to get the timestamp of monday at 00:00 of the current week in python

You could use `timedelta` method from `datetime` package.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()
monday = now - timedelta(days = now.weekday())
print(monday)
```

Output

```
2020-01-27 08:47:01
```

Comment: I think this is it

Comment: Yes, this did it for me. Thank you

Comment: this code does not give Monday at 00:00